# Sass nested extend inside is own parent

Tags: css, sass, nested, extend

I want to know if it's possible to achive this code:

```
section#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
section#content > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-left:60px;
}
```

By doing this:

```
section#content {
    position: absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    & > div {
        @extend section#content;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding-left:60px;
    }
}
```

because right now my output is :

```
section#content, section#content > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    section#content > div, section#content > div > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding-left:60px;
    }
```

as you can see there is another "> div" for each class because the extend is calling itseft...
Sorry for my english i'm french

Comment: I suggest using the placeholder selector instead of extend.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Peiwen. I'm new in Compass/SASS so for people who looking for a solution here mine :

```
%full-block {
    position: absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
section#content {
    @extend %full-block;
    & > div {
        @extend %full-block;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding-left:60px;
    }
}
```